# Including js and css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying out this simple css and js password strength checker. It works very nicely when the css and js is included in the file as below. If I put the js in a seperate file however and include it in this file it will not work. Also if I put the css in an external css file it wont style the page.

To include it I was simply putting:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js"></script>
```

I dont see what Im doing wrong or is it to do with the code and it needs to be in the same file for some reason?

the file is a php file because I will later be adding php to it but that doesnt change anything does it?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>strength check</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #passwordStrength {
        height:10px;
        display:block;
        float:left; 
    }
    .strength0 {
        width:150px;
        background:#cccccc;
    }     
    .strength1 {
        width:20px;
        background:#ff0000;
    } 
    .strength2 {
        width:40px;    
        background:#ff5f5f;
    } 
    .strength3 { 
        width:60px;
        background:#56e500;
    }
    .strength4 {
        background:#4dcd00;
        width:80px;
    } 
    .strength5 { 
        background:#399800;
        width:150px;
    } 
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function passwordStrength(password) {

        var desc = new Array();
        desc[0] = "Very Weak";
        desc[1] = "Weak";
        desc[2] = "Better";
        desc[3] = "Medium";
        desc[4] = "Strong";
        desc[5] = "Strongest";

        var score = 0;

        //if password bigger than 6 give 1 point
        if (password.length > 6) score++;

        //if password has both lower and uppercase characters give 1 point      
        if ((password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) score++;

        //if password has at least one number give 1 point
        if (password.match(/\d+/)) score++;

        //if password has at least one special caracther give 1 point
        if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) score++;
        //if password bigger than 12 give another 1 point
        if (password.length > 12) score++;

        document.getElementById("passwordDescription").innerHTML = desc[score];
        document.getElementById("passwordStrength").className = "strength" + score;
    }​
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <input type="password" caption="password" name="password" onkeyup="passwordStrength(this.value);" size="60">
    <div style="font-size: 10px"; id="passwordDescription">Password Strength</div>
    <div class="strength0" id="passwordStrength"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it is seperate file , how do you include it?

Comment: How are you including the js file?  It might be worth showing this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `/` at the begining of your links :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
```

Those `/` mean your files are at the root of your domain.

Comment: Oh right thanks. I thought that just meant that it was down a directory.

Comment: Use `../` to go down a directory!

Answer (score 0):

1. Do whatever you tried again.
2. Open the page in firefox.
3. View Source
4. In the source page, you can see you scripts and css files as a links.
5. Click the link. it will show page cannot be displayed.

In that case, your include location is wrong!

Place the css and js in the correct place, until the step 5 shows you some thing other than page cannot be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what server you are using, but if you are working with Tomcat you need to lose the leading slash of the source path.

Try:

```
css/style.css
```

instead of

```
/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the paths without the starting slashes – if you have everything in a sub directory of your server, then the slashes might break the path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
```

In HTML5 you can also get rid of the type attributes (just in case you use a HTML5 doctype).